# Mono, C# Console, Putty - Arrow Keys Becoming Null Characters

Tags: c#, mono, putty

I'm creating a basic C# console application which runs on my debian server using Mono for compilation.

I'm using PuTTY to communicate with the server & send commands to the app I'm creating.

The problem:
**If I try to go to previous command, next command, move left/right in entered input => using arrow keys - nothing happens!**

When I investigated the problem, found out that every arrow key I press is send to input as a null character '\0' (found out by iterating over every key in output of Console.Readline()).

**And yes, it works fine on Windows (10)!**

I ask you:

> Is it problem of PuTTY or it's settings ?
>   Is it problem related to Mono or my own code ?
>   Do I just have to deal with it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cecilio is correct, `ReadLine` does not implement that functionality. What you are seeing on Windows is "Shell" integration.

[StreamReader.ReadLine](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamreader.readline%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

> Reads a line of characters from the current stream and returns the data as a string.

If you are looking for the same *shell-style* integration without using a readline lib you should look at the `LineEditor` class:

[getline.cs: Partying like its 1988](http://tirania.org/blog/archive/2008/Aug-26.html)

Note: the source links are out of date in the blog, so use [Mono/Mono](https://github.com/mono/mono/blob/b7a308f660de8174b64697a422abfc7315d07b8c/mcs/tools/csharp/getline.cs) at Github.

```
using Mono.Terminal;

    LineEditor le = new LineEditor ("MyApp");
    while ((s = le.Edit ("prompt> ", "")) != null)
        Console.WriteLine ("You typed: " + s);
```

> It supports the regular cursor editing, Emacs-like editing commands, history, incremental search in the history as well as history loading and saving.

Comment: So what you're saying is that, to added functionality that is supported by native Windows console, I have to use the snippet to add this functionality under linux ? Am I right ? #PartlySleeping #2AM

Answer (score 1):

The ReadLine function does not implement the history/edit functionality you are expecting. It just reads a string, nothing more. **EDIT**: But it does!

Comment: Ops. My bad. On windows, are you running it with mono too, or with .net?

Comment: I'm using Mono "just" to compile/build the app to be able to run it on Linux (Debian).